# '_comp' cannot be used as a function error

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am getting "'_comp' cannot be used as a function" error in the stl_algobase.h header file. Here is my code and the part of the header file that is supposed to have the error.
code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

void subsqr(int a[10][10]){
    //int s[][10];
    for(int i =1;i<5;i++){
        for(int j = 1;j<5;j++){
            if(a[i][j] == 1){
                a[i][j] = min(a[i][j-1], a[i-1][j],a[i-1][j-1]) + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
            cout<<a[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    int a[10][10] = {{0,1,1,0,1}, {1,1,0,1,0}, {1,1,1,0}, {1,1,1,1,0}, {1,1,1,1,1}, {0,0,0,0,0}};

    subsqr(a);  
    return 0;
}
```

stl_algobase.h:

```
 template<typename _Tp, typename _Compare>
    inline const _Tp&
    min(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b, _Compare __comp)
    {
      //return __comp(__b, __a) ? __b : __a;
      if (__comp(__b, __a))
            return __b;
      return __a;
    }
```

The compiler says that the error is in the line

```
if (__comp(__b, __a))
```

Comment: Aren't double underscore prefixed names potentially reserved by the compiler? May be a conflict.

Comment: Which `min()` function do you think you're calling?

Comment: Please people don't post irrelevant comments about double underscores.

Comment: Pretty sure that `__comp` came from the standard library.

Answer (score 8):

It may not be the problem but the header of your min function specifies it needs 3 parameters : 2 of type __Tp and one of type _Compare but in your program, you call it with 3 type __TP :

```
a[i][j] = min(a[i][j-1], a[i-1][j],a[i-1][j-1]) + 1; // the third parameter is an int, not a function !
```

EDIT : If you want to find out the min of three numbers, consider [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424173/c-find-the-smallest-amongst-3-numbers), with ints and float it is not needed to specify a comp function.
For a quick fix, replace the line I highlighted with this one :

```
std::min({a[i][j-1], a[i-1][j], a[i-1][j-1]});
```