# Error when using std::min "no matching function for call to ‘min(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’"

Tags: c++, c++11, std, min

Following https://stackoverflow.com/a/9424211/3368959 I am trying to compare three numbers:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::cout << std::min({2,5,1}) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But the compiler gives me the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘min(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
```

However, the code compiles just fine when using

```
std::min(std::min(2,5),1)
```

But the first way should work with the c++11 standard. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I take it that you actually mean C++11?

Comment: `#include <algorithm>`? As to why it works using the 2-arg version, I can only assume the implementation of the Standard Library you are using splits the algorithm header up in some way, and you are getting some transitive include through `iostream`, but this is certainly not guaranteed to work.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, I have edited it. I am using CLion and CMakeLists includes the line: set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

Comment: @BoBTFish Thank you! That solved it =)

Answer (score 12):

As @BoBTFish [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44561919/error-when-using-stdmin-no-matching-function-for-call-to-minbrace-enclosed#comment76112896_44561919):

In order to use `template <class T> T min (initializer_list<T> il)` one needs to include `<algorithm>` as is mentioned [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min/).